# Cannot find python library

Tags: python, package

I'm trying to run [indic nlp library](http://anoopkunchukuttan.github.io/indic_nlp_library/) and there's an import statement

```
from indicnlp.tokenize import indic_tokenize
```

but nowhere is it mentioned how to install indicnlp or maybe I don't understand. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: did you try pip?!

Comment: it is mentioned in the github website under configuration section
https://github.com/anoopkunchukuttan/indic_nlp_library

Comment: @chakri It's just setting some directories to path.

Comment: You need to download source and put it in the path or copy paste the content in src directory to site-packages of your python

Answer (score 1):

`$ pip3 install indic`

This command worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Below installation worked for me.

pip install indic-nlp-library

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to install with pip:

```
$ pip install --user indic
```

Comment: it still says No module named indicnlp

Answer (score 0):

Download get-pip.py from below link  [get-pip.py](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwim0YCdzIbXAhUBjLwKHW5IASQQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbootstrap.pypa.io%2Fget-pip.py&usg=AOvVaw0zKVO_zW0nkF7s0zdjWFNj)

And download pip as

python get-pip.py

After that you can install modules using pip install modulename

Comment: I want to know how to install that specific package

Comment: pip install indic ?

Comment: indic != indicnlp

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work i.e. "No module named indicnlp"

Comment: Download from https://github.com/anoopkunchukuttan/indic_nlp_library/zipball/master and unzip in your python library directory. Then you can import it in your code. `>>> from indicnlp.tokenize import indic_tokenize
>>> `

Comment: where did you unzip the file downloaded from http://anoopkunchukuttan.github.io/indic_nlp_library/ ? it should be in side C:\Python27\Lib if C:\Python27 is your installation directory

Comment: It should be in C:\Python27\Lib\Site-Packages

Answer (score 0):

#for windows

-First search inside the window search box if there is a package called indicnlp

-if the folder contains tokenize.py you have to copy the path of indicnlp

-go to system variables and edit the path variable to add the copied path.

-restart your Jupyter notebook or whichever environment you are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).